# Clarifying layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

This is my layout:

```
    <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit">

                <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@drawable/ic_assignment" />

                <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editName"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
               android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit">

                <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:id="@+id/img"
                   android:background="@drawable/ic_person_outline" />

                <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editUsername"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

I don't understand  why if I put match_parent on the imageView and editTex, the latter do not occupy the entire screen in height.
Instead I get two rows as I wanted but I do not understand why

Why?

Comment: So currently it gives you 2 `ImageViews` underneath each other with a `EditText` next to each `ImageView`?

Comment: yes and i don't understand why if i use match_parent on height

Comment: It's because you have 2 LinearLayouts underneath each other and both of their orientation is set to horizontal.

Comment: Yes, but if I put the full screen height it should not occupy the whole screen?

Comment: Try this.. in both `LinearLayouts` `android:layout_weight="1"` and set both `LinearLayouts` hight to 0dp. This will make it match the parent and take equal space.

Comment: Tanks =)!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:orientation="horizontal"              
           android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit">

            <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_assignment" />

            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/editName"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
           android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit">

            <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/img"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_person_outline" />

            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/editUsername"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/under_line_edit"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```